# database get request output to display in return text- react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, expo, get-request

We are trying to fetch the name value from the local database and storing it as tlName variable, we want to display the dynamic value of tlName in return function.

Currently, we can see the values in console.log but not in the emulator app screen and getting an error. How to resolve this issue?

```
import React , {useState} from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
//import { View } from 'react-native-web';
import logo from '../assets/Logo3.jpg';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

import {
    InnerContainer, PageLogo,
    PageTitle,
    SubTitle,
    StyledFormArea,
    StyledButton, ButtonText,
    Line,
    WelcomeContainer, WelcomeImage, Avatar
} from '../components/Styles';
import axios from 'axios';

const tlName = null;
const name = null;

const Dummy2 = ({navigation}) => {
    /**************Test for get request */
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("testing get request")
        const url = 'http://10.1.46.41:8090/api/users/';
            axios
                .get(url)
                .then((response) => {
                    const result = response.data;
                    console.log(result[3].Name)
                    name= result[3].Name;
                    console.log(name)
                    tlName = name;

                }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error.JSON);
                setSubmitting(false);
                handleMesssage("An error occured. Check your network and try again");
        
            });
    }, 5000)
    return(   
            <>
                <StatusBar style = "light"/>
                <InnerContainer>
                    <WelcomeImage source={require('../assets/Logo3.jpg')}/>
                    <WelcomeContainer>
                    <PageTitle welcome = {true}> Trial for getting data </PageTitle>
                    <SubTitle welcome = {true}>Your request has been sent to the Team lead of {tlName}</SubTitle>
                    <SubTitle welcome = {true}>Kindly await their response</SubTitle>
                    <StyledFormArea>  
                    <Avatar source={require('../assets/Logo3.jpg')} />
                        <StyledButton onPress = {() => {navigation.navigate('Welcome')}}>
                            <ButtonText> Okay </ButtonText>
                        </StyledButton>
                    <Line />
                    </StyledFormArea> 
                </WelcomeContainer>
                </InnerContainer>
            </>     
    );
};

export default Dummy2;
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? And does the emulator have access to the API?

Comment: Yes the API is working fine, and we are getting this error: Unhandled Rejection(ReferenceError): SetSubmitting is not defined